# Where can we find full documentation of Mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax, meta

When you google "Mathjax Documentation", you find documentation of configuring mathjax in browsers/servers not actual commands or reference to how to use it.

[Here is the documentation of Mathajax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/)

This is quick guide available on math meta stackexchange.

[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

But where can I find full official manual of using Mathjax i.e. command/instruction ?

Comment: In http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html there are some pages for users http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/mathematics.html

Comment: @Calvin Khor that's limited and even there configuration is mentioned more than commands.  Why there's not exhaustive official user guide? If you have one, can you post here?

Comment: I don't know why there isn't, and I don't know why you think I have one. I'm not hiding one from you.

Comment: As this question really has nothing to do with Math SE, I am closing it.  I will also note that the use of bit.ly links is somewhat off putting---shortened links are not needed here, and have to potential to hid malicious links.

Comment: @Xander Well, MathJax is a *massive* part of using this site, so official documentation would be beneficial to many interested people here. We have a "basic tutorial and quick reference" question, which I personally find annoying and unusable, so I don't see how seeking official documentation is off topic rather than super-relevant!

Comment: @user1729 A universal MathJax guide is likely not of much use, as every site on the internet which implements MathJax must choose which features to implement (or not implement).  There are commands which will work some places, but not others.  The local (to Math SE) guide linked in the question here is likely the *best* you are going to be able to do regarding what TeX-like code is going to work here.

Comment: @Xander so maybe an answer explaining this would be preferable to closing the question? And maybe also the "basic tutorial and quick reference" should be renamed to something which better reflects it's "the best (we) can do" status?

Comment: You can find the source files of mathjax [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/) , it's written in typescript. I guess it would be good to know which components are included in the version used in math.se

Comment: @user1729 why should we answer generic support questions for MathJax on the meta of math.se? If the question is actually not a generic support question for MathJax but about this site, it should be made clear. Moreover, the poster should explain what they actually want/need.  The risk of running into an XY problem is quite high here.

Comment: I closed it again. Several reasons might apply. I opted for this one in that I find the question unfocused.